# Searching an array by value and index

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary-search

I have a sorted array of integers, on which I want to perform searching. This array can have repeated values. **If I search for an element that is repeated, then it should return the index of the first instance of the element**.

If I use the `Arrays.binarySearch()`, then it doesn't necessarily give out the index of the first instance of the element searched. Example can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702576/binary-search-if-array-contains-duplicates):

```
int[] A = {10,20,21,24,24,24,24,24,30,40,45} ;
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(A,24) ;
```

Where, `idx` will be `5`. I want it to be `3`. I solved this problem earlier by making a class `Pair` like :

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>
{
    int value, index ;
    Pair(int v,int i)
    {
        this.value = v ;
        this.index = i ;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair p)
    {
        if(p.value<this.value)
            return 1 ;
        else if(p.value>this.value)
            return -1 ;
        else 
        {
            if(p.index<this.index)
                return 1 ;
            else if(p.index>this.index)
                return -1 ;
            else return 0 ;
        }
    }
}
```

Which when searched with `Collections.binarySearch(new Pair(24,Integer.MIN_VALUE))` (for a list of `Pair`s) would return a `3`. 
The code then would be:

```
int[] A = {10,20,21,24,24,24,24,24,30,40,45} ;

        List<Pair> L = new ArrayList<Pair>() ;

        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
        {
            L.add(new Pair(A[i],i)) ;
        }
        int idx = Collections.binarySearch(L,new Pair(24,Integer.MIN_VALUE)) ;
        if(idx<0) idx = -idx-1 ;
        System.out.println(idx) ;
```

`Pair` works like this:
It has two variables `value` and `index`, which are the value of the element of the sorted array, and index of the element in the array. The `compareTo` method is overridden in order to allow `Collections.binarySearch()` to perform comparisons. The comparisons can be defined like this:

- If the current `value` is greater or less, then the order is decide by `value`.
- If `value`s are the same, then order is decided using `index`.

My question is, can this be done in a less messy way? Anything that is shorter, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at below piece of code. Made changes to original binary search code: `l` and `r` are the left and right range respectively

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int num, int l,int r) {
    int mid = (l+r)/2;
    if(arr[mid] == num && (mid>0&& arr[mid-1]!=num) || mid==0) {            
        return mid;
    }       
    else if(arr[mid] > num || (mid > l && arr[mid] == num && arr[mid-1] == num)) {
        return binarySearch(arr, num, l, mid);
    }else {
        return binarySearch(arr, num, mid, r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is just dealing with the array `A`, you can find the first index using the following code below:

```
    int[] A = { 10, 20, 21, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 30, 40, 45 };
    // key is a[i], value is the index
    Map<Integer, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        hmap.putIfAbsent(A[i], i);
    }
```

If a number was already present we don't increment the value of `i` as we need the first index of the repeated number. This way the first index of a repeated number is always maintained.

Now to fetch the index all we need to do is `hmap.get(24)`.

Comment: @Eugene That comment was for the previous answer of NicholasK. I am deleting that comment now.

Comment: @NicholasK that's not bad, can be simplified to `for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            hmap.putIfAbsent(A[i], i);
        }`. but, you are iterating all the elements in the array only to put them in a map, then do a look-up. that would be `O(n) + O(1) = O(n)`. If you are iterating, you can do a simple `if` and find it; this way you are totally ignoring the nature of the sorted array

Comment: @Eugene : Yes agreed. But the look up is O(1), so just thought of sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Just an hacky solution.

```
double[] A = { 10, 20, 21, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 30, 40, 45 };
int key = 24;
int idx = -(Arrays.binarySearch(A, key - 0.5) + 1);
if (A[idx] != key)
    System.out.println("Key not exist!");
else
    System.out.println("First occurance of key is " + idx);
```

Binary search is finding occurence of number, if not found returns the index of number if  the number will be added to sorted list.

Comment: Beautiful and clever!

Comment: But this would require creating a new `float` array (+ `O(n)` space). This might require a manual function of 3 lines of code, atleast. But still, a good answer.

Comment: Of course but integer can be convert to float type. or you can add integer to float list without casting. Just an initalize array as float but add integer  with user input or read from file or whatelse :) also this is the another hacky.

Comment: @drowny this is *too* hacky and subject to break; and no an integer can not be safely put into a float.

Comment: I added just an optional solution. @Eugene but you are right thanks for your suggest :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @KevinAnderson , i updated the post.

Comment: Glad I could contribute to the silliness (;->)

Comment: All of us are hacky person now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the best out of both binary search *and* linear search?  Use binary search to get the index of *an* occurrence of your number, then search linearly back from there to find the *first* occurrence:

```
int[] A = { 10, 20, 21, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 30, 40, 45 };
int key = 24;
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(A, key);
while (idx > 0) {
    if (A[idx - 1] != key)
        break;
    --idx;
}
if (idx < 0)
    System.out.println("Key " + key + " not found");
else
    System.out.println("First index of key " + key + " is " + idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create your own Binary Search function that wont stop the search unless its the first time the number we are searching appear (the number before it is different)

try this Binary Search function:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] arr,int x)
{
    int maxi=arr.length-1;
    int mini=0;
    int mid;
    while(mini<=maxi)
    {
        mid=(maxi+mini)/2;
        if(arr[mid]==x&&(mid==0||arr[mid-1]!=x))
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]<x)
        {
            mini=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            maxi=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Uri! I can do this, but that defeats the purpose of my question. I want to have something that does this concisely. The loc still remains approximately the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the index and search backwards to find the first one, if it exists. This will be `O(log(n) + m)`; where `m` is how many times this element that was found is present in the array (number of duplicates of this element in the array).

```
 private static int findFirstIndex(List<Pair> pairs, Pair search) {
    int idx = Collections.binarySearch(pairs, search);
    if (idx < 0) {
        return idx = -idx - 1;
    }

    for (; idx > 1; --idx) {
        if (pairs.get(idx - 1).compareTo(pairs.get(idx)) != 0) {
            return idx;
        }
    }

    return idx;
}
```